# Warning! Internet Explorer should not be used error, on mobile browsers

Tags: administrator, joomla-4.x, mobile-detection

After some problems with a Joomla 4( beta 6) install on ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx tried another instance for test purposes. This time on an Ubuntu 20 server with Litespeed( Open LS). Wich I don't know too much about, just that it should similarly work with Joomla to some point as Apache but being less resource demanding.

Everything works good except one thing. No matter what ( Android)mobile browser I choose, whenever I visit the backend of my test joomla install I get no CSS/JS rendered and the error message: **Warning! Internet Explorer should not be used**

If someone knows what could be in culprit to help me make some light I'd be gratefull. Rewrite rules of my install are the ones from thedefault Joomla 4 .htaccess. Don't know about any missing PHP dependency as I didn't get any warning from Joomla.

Comment: Try running it from a PC, so you can see the browser console and why the CSS/JS are not loading.  Just a guess from what you've said so far, I'd say that you're having an issue with mixed content.  Mixed content occurs when HTML on a website loads over a secure HTTPS connection (thanks to a recently installed SSL certificate) but other content, such as images, video content, stylesheets, and scripts, continue to load over an insecure HTTP connection.

Comment: Checking the admin from the PC i see that just some of the JS doesn't load properly. I'll check what you said. My confusion was that I got besides the non loading JS/CSS on mobile, also the Warning I was using Internet Explorer. Wich wasn't the case.

Comment: Yeah, that warning message can be misleading.  IE is known for stopping JS from loading, so it's pretty common for programmers to write the error into their code as; "IF JS doesn't load, spit out IE error message".  :)

Comment: After your reply found out that the problem happens on PC too( didn't saw it before probably due to my site being cached). And it happens afterI enable URL rewritting

Comment: Welcome to JSE @Ckubs, please take our [tour].

Comment: @Ckubs you'll need to examine the URLs before and after URL rewriting is enabled, and then check your nginx configuration. In case you haven't seen this already, here's a Joomla document for nginx: https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx

Comment: Nginx is on the working site. For the otherone installed Open Litespeed, Don't know that much about it just that it should be mostly compatible with Apache configs, but less resource demanding. And I sawthat Apache is better supported by Joomla than Nginx.

Comment: It feels like this may be where things are getting confused. Nginx doesn't use htaccess, while apache and litespeed do use it, but differently from each other.

Comment: I was maybe a bit confusing :) Have a personal joomla site on Nginx. On wich I have to always fix something, Nginx related. Since the tutorials/documentation involving Nginx are les present on the internet than Apache ones, decided to install a second test Joomla on another server configuration. But with Open Litesped as, based on their documentation should be less resource intensive than Apache and should work with Apache rewrite rules. And the problem from my post is related to the second install.